# Match value with alternate position

Tags: mysql

I want to self join a table on a column having value with alternate position, specifying the position is easy for one record, but I have thousands of record with different values. I'm not sure how to do it generally. I tried to match it by palindrome using reverse() but of course it's not the way to do it. I have a value like below:

| Block | Range |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1-10 |
| A | 10-1 |

I want to match the value as if 1-10=10-1 in general way.

Comment: Reparse your value to 'least-greatest' then join.

Comment: can you put an example of the table data?

Answer (score 0):

As @Akina mentions, I tried parsing the table data with following query:

```
SELECT t.`Block`, 
LEAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.`Range`,'-',1) ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.`Range`,'-',-1)) leastNumber,
GREATEST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.`Range`,'-',1) ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.`Range`,'-',-1)) greatestNumber
 FROM test_table t
```

which will give you results

| Block | leastNumber | greatestNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| A | 1 | 10 |

And then may be you can join them with ease.